# While select in mysql stored procuder

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, select, while-loop

i will try a select into my Stored Procedure like a while

#### e.g.

```
while ( select * from t where t.c = 1 into test_t )
{
    var_t_e = test_t.c;
}
```

i hope i can be helped here. :)

Comment: Try phrasing this as a question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this documentation on using [cursors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html) in your stored procedure.

**Edit based on comment:**

I'm not quite sure what you're asking for based on your comment.  If you can clarify I can try and give you a more specific example.  Here is a [link](http://www.kbedell.com/2009/03/02/a-simple-example-of-a-mysql-stored-procedure-that-uses-a-cursor/) that goes through the steps of producing a stored procedure with a cursor with some good information on the individual steps and also when you shouldn't use a cursor.  This may be more helpful for you.

Comment: Tanks i think its make my problem out :) can you make a sample if i use 2 on each time? :) and tanks for the link.